# persist local scope variables with before_request hook in python bottle

Tags: python, bottle

I would like to use the before_request hook to load the request body into json format so I don't have to do it for each request as I know this is something I will need to have with any api call. Is there a way I can persist the data dict into the view functions.

```
@app.hook('before_request')
def before():
    data = json.loads(request.data)

@app.route("/start", method='POST')
def start():
   foo = data[bar] #how do i do this??
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Every page call is a separate request context and while you're handling that call, you'll have access to the request data. There's no need for you to duplicate that in a JSON or dictionary structure. If you need to cache app settings or other static values that won't change with each request, you can store them in a config file or global/module variables.